# Camera API 2 preview in fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera

I'm currently working on a app where there is a **fragment** that is a **preview of a camera (API 2)**, kind of snapchat's home page camera. I've been looking for the solution everywhere with no luck.That's why i'm asking here today. Here's my code sample:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Size;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mTextureView = (TextureView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textureView);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT = 0;

    private TextureView mTextureView;
    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            setupCamera(width, height);
            connectCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

        }
    };

    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraDeviceStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            mCameraDevice = camera;
            startPreview();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            camera.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            camera.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
    };

    private CaptureRequest.Builder mCaptureRequestBuilder;

    private static SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270);
    }

    private static class CompareSizeByArea implements Comparator<Size> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs){
            return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() /
                    (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
        }
    }

    private static int sensorToDeviceRotation(CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics, int deviceOrientation){
        int sensorOrientation = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
        deviceOrientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(deviceOrientation);
        return(sensorOrientation + deviceOrientation + 360) % 360;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        closeCamera();

        stopBackgroundThread();

        super.onPause();
    }

    private void closeCamera() {
        if(mCameraDevice != null) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
    }

    private HandlerThread mBackgroundHandlerThread;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;

    private String mCameraId;

    private Size mPreviewSize;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        startBackgroundThread();

        if(mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
            setupCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
            connectCamera();
        } else {
            mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
        }
    }

    public void  onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
        super.getActivity().onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
        if(hasFocus){
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    }

    private  void setupCamera(int width, int height) {
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            for (String cameraId : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
                if(cameraCharacteristics.get(cameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) ==
                        CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT){
                    continue;
                }
                StreamConfigurationMap map = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                int deviceOrientation = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                int totalRotation = sensorToDeviceRotation(cameraCharacteristics, deviceOrientation);
                boolean swapRotation = totalRotation == 90 || totalRotation == 270;
                int rotatedWidth = width;
                int rotatedHeight = height;
                if (swapRotation){
                    rotatedWidth = height;
                    rotatedHeight = width;
                }
                mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight);
                mCameraId = cameraId;
                return;
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void connectCamera() {
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraDeviceStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                } else {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This app requires access to camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT);
            }
        } else {
            cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraDeviceStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
        }
        }catch(CameraAccessException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startPreview() {
        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

        try {
            mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface),
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            try {
                                session.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(),
                                        null, mBackgroundHandler);
                            } catch (CameraAccessException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to connect to camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("PROJETDILEMMA");
        mBackgroundHandlerThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundHandlerThread.getLooper());
    }

    private void stopBackgroundThread(){
        mBackgroundHandlerThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundHandlerThread.join();
            mBackgroundHandlerThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height) {
        List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<Size>();
        for(Size option : choices){
            if(option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * height/width &&
                    option.getWidth() >= width && option.getHeight() >= height) {
                bigEnough.add(option);
            }
        }
        if(bigEnough.size() > 0){
            return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizeByArea());
        } else {
            return choices[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I run the project, the mistake I get is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at chom.com.dilemma17.CameraFragment.onCreateView(CameraFragment.java:41)
```

Which has something to do with:

```
mTextureView = (TextureView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textureView);
```

that I completely ignore..
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Per your error, it looks like this is occurring because you are calling `getView()` within the `onCreateView()` method. [`getView()` is supposed to get the layout that is returned by `onCreateView()`.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView%28%29)

Since your view hasn't been created yet inside `onCreateView()`, you should instead use the inflated layout to grab your reference:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);

    mTextureView = (TextureView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textureView);

    return rootView;
}
```